# Evaluation performance for support vector machine

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning

How can i calculated the specificity and sensitivity of svm classifier if i get accuracy for acute and chronic stroke is 100 %?. I am using matlab for the classification. Kindly give me a guide to do this evaluation because i do know the formula but don't know to use it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/roc.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

TPR is sensitivity.

FPR = 1 - specificity.

So you will be able to calculate both specificity and sensitivity by using roc method.

Comment: In my opinion if the accuracy i get is 100% so the sensitivity and specificity is also 100%, is it correct?